# How to Integrate Rest API Source Connector with Kafka Connect?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have Confluent 5.0 on my local machine and trying to reading data from Rest API using Rest API Source Connect which is not part of confluent. till now i have used confluent inbuilt connectors only. Rest API source connect is open source and available on github https://github.com/llofberg/kafka-connect-rest

I have downloaded this connector from github and got stuck here.

Can anybody tell me the process to integrate this connector with confluent or how can i use this to pull the data from Rest API?

Comment: Can you clarify "got stuck"? That's about the same as saying "it's not working"  http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer:* There is no single answer to add an external Kafka Connect plugin; Confluent provides the Kafka Connect Maven plugin, but that doesn't mean people use it or even Maven to package their code.

If it is not on the Confluent Hub, then you'll have to build it by hand.

---

1) Clone the repo, and build it (install Git and Maven first)

```
git clone https://github.com/llofberg/kafka-connect-rest && cd kafka-connect-rest
mvn clean package
```

2) Create a directory for it on all Connect workers, similar to the other Connectors of Confluent Platform

```
mkdir $CONFLUENT_HOME/share/java/kafka-connect-rest
```

3) Find each of the shaded JARs (this connector happens to make multiple JARs, I don't know why...)

```
find . -iname "*shaded.jar" -type f

./kafka-connect-transform-from-json/kafka-connect-transform-from-json-plugin/target/kafka-connect-transform-from-json-plugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar
./kafka-connect-transform-add-headers/target/kafka-connect-transform-add-headers-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar
./kafka-connect-transform-velocity-eval/target/kafka-connect-transform-velocity-eval-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar
./kafka-connect-rest-plugin/target/kafka-connect-rest-plugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar
```

4) Copy each of these files into the `$CONFLUENT_HOME/share/java/kafka-connect-rest` folder created in step 2 for each Connect worker

5) Make sure your `plugin.path` of the `connect-*.properties` file points at the full path to `$CONFLUENT_HOME/share/java`

At this point, you've done [all the steps that are listed in the README to build the thing and setup the plugin path](https://github.com/llofberg/kafka-connect-rest#building-and-running-spring-example-in-docker), just not in Docker.

6) Start Connect (Distributed)

7) Hit `GET /connector-plugins` to verify the thing loaded.

8) Configure and send JSON payload to `POST /connectors`

I have not used this connector before, so I do not know how to configure it. Maybe see the [examples](https://github.com/llofberg/kafka-connect-rest/blob/master/examples/spring/config/source.json) or follow along with [@rmoff's blog post](https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-wrangling-apache-kafka-ksql) before the KSQL stuff

Comment: Thank you @cricket_007. I already had done this part except GET /Connector-plugins. as i followed the same instruction and got stuck (couldn't run) GET / Connector-plugin or POST / Connectors command. On confluent hiting ./bin/connect-standalone GET /connector-plugins getting err like ```java.io.FileNotFoundException: GET (No such file or directory)```

Comment: You're not supposed to run that from the CLI, but from POSTMAN because it's a REST API, and I mentioned to start `connect-distributed`, not `connect-standalone`